# Jio Gigafiber Router - Blinking Red LED

Tags: wireless-networking, router

A few days ago, my Jio Gigafiber router stopped working properly. Though it created 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz bands, there was no internet connectivity. The red LED light on the router started blinking. I called the technical support team, but they just said they would send a technician (who never arrived). Is there any way I can fix the problem myself?

Comment: The best you could do on your end is unplug the router and plug it back in. The red blinking light means that it failed to sync with the ISP. Otherwise call again and see if you can get a technician to come out.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Yes, I called the support team and they sent an engineer to fix it. The issue was due to some problem at ISP's (Jio) end.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue. Suddenly jio network connection got stopped and red led light was flashing in the Jio Gigafiber router. Firstly, i switched off the power cable and switched on after 10 seconds. Problem persisted. Then i removed both power cable and network cable in the router and inserted it again and after some 10 seconds. I switched on. First Red LED was flashing and after few minutes green LED light was flashing. Bingo! and green LED light got stable. The red led light flashing is due to low optical network signal / fiber cable cut.

Comment: It seems our issues are different. My issue was due to some fault in the cables under some roads. It was fixed by engineers working at Jio.